When I open Crystal Report I get the following error: The Document's Format is either unsupported
I have recently installed upgrades to Visual Studio (2022) community version. I had installed SAP Crystal Reports for CR for Visual Studio SP32 64 bit installer (VS 2022 and above) and SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (SP33) runtime (64-bit) Now my reports will not run, and I an unable to access them inside Visual Studio. I get the following error: The Document's Format is either unsupported or the document contains binary characters, opening with a different application.
Has anyone solved this issue of Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2022?

Make sure that the SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio package and the runtime (SP32 or SP33) are both from the same version series.
